# JavaScript typewriter script not working

Tags: javascript

Well basically I tried to make a typewriter script from scratch, for my little terminal web app junkie xD

Well, I've got this JavaScript thingy:

```
var str = "dude";
var num = 1000;
for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
var num = num + 100;
var dude = str[i];
setTimeout('document.getElementById("guide").innerHTML +=dude;', num);
}
```

which obviously writes to a `div` with the `ID` `guide`, "d" "u" "d" "e" in 100 milisecond intervals, but guess what ?

It doesn't do that !!

NOW what it DOES do it print "e" as many times as they are characters in the string, dude!!

:|

Thank you,

I'm probably super stupid

but I'd love a fix!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you considered the fact that the loop will finish running even before your first Timeout call starts running ?

Comment: @SreenathS Yeah, I was thinking thats what it could be... how would you delay the loop ?

Comment: call a `method` from `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` and do the `innerHTML` thing inside that method

Comment: wat ? the only differience I see is that it is escaped more! what was wrong with my original code ? what did you change / @SreenathS why?

Comment: your code will throw an error saying `dude is not defined` in some browsers, its got to do with the scope of variable `dude`. which browser are you using ?

Comment: is appears that the fix you provided got deleted!

Comment: hehe.. i said i hated that code.. do you really want that piece of code ?

Comment: do you mind re-commenting it ?

Comment: what do you hate about it ? and yes, I use Safari

Comment: ah, I guessed the code, and yes, I found it

Comment: what do you hate about it ? @SreenathS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a small function that accept 2 parameters: the text and the time :

```
function defiredWriteText(text,time, index){
    if(index === null || index === undefined) {
        index=0;
    }
    setTimeout(function (){
        var dude = text[index];
        document.getElementById("guide").innerHTML += dude;
        if(index < text.length-1)
            defiredWriteText(text, time, ++index);
    }, time)
}
```

sample: http://jsfiddle.net/3e3yx/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to call a function in setTimeout like the following:

```
var str = "dude";
var num = 1000;
for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
  var num = num + 100;
  var dude = str[i];
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("guide").innerHTML +=dude;
  }, num);
}
```

or

```
var str = "dude";
var num = 1000;
for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
  var num = num + 100;
  var dude = str[i];
  setTimeout(changeHtml, num);
}

function changeHtml() {
  document.getElementById("guide").innerHTML +=dude;
}
```

If you want a more precise 100 millisecond interval you might want to use setInterval

```
var myInterval = setInterval(changeHtml, 100);
var len = str.length;
var current = 0;

function changeHtml() {
  if(current < len) {
    document.getElementById("guide").innerHTML +=str[current];
  }
  else {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
  }
  current++;
}
```