# Replacing a GIF image with another after it has finished playing?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm really new to coding and for my first project I'm working on a blog theme. For the most part I've been following a lot of tutorials and it's worked out pretty well but I'm kinda stuck on this one issue.

What I'd like to do is have a gif image play once, and then be replaced by a second gif image that loops.

The idea was to have it appear that a line of text was being typed in an older looking computer font, and then the little underscore that represents where the character is being placed would continue to blink after the text is finished typing.

I'm not really sure if this is something that would require javascript or not, like I said I'm pretty new to the whole coding thing so help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: The biggest issue would be timing the switch, since as far as I know there isn't anything to tell you that the GIFs animation has come to an end and it's starting over again. If you know the exact value for the length of the first animation, however, you could use `setTimeout` to do the switch.

Comment: The length of time the gif plays for in a browser is highly dependent on the connection speed though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably best forgetting about animated gifs and sticking to JavaScript and CSS for this piece of work.

A similar question to yours has already been answered, how to write a script that emulates a typewriter:
[JavaScript typewriter script not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263941/javascript-typewriter-script-not-working)

I forked Thomas's answer from this question and added a blinking underscore like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/t3Zbd/

JavaScript:

```
var str = "typing";
var num = 450;
defiredWriteText(str, num);
function defiredWriteText(text,time, index){
    if(index === null || index === undefined) {
        index=0;
    }
    setTimeout(function (){
        var dude = text[index];
        document.getElementById("guide").innerHTML += dude;
        if(index < text.length-1)
            defiredWriteText(text, time, ++index);
        else
             document.getElementById("underscore").style.display = 'inline';
    }, time)
}
```

CSS:

```
#underscore {
    display: none;
    animation: blink 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
}
@keyframes blink {
    to {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<span id="guide"></span><span id="underscore">_</span>
```

The JavaScript itself is fairly standard, but you need to be careful with the CSS and carry out some cross browsing testing. I believe you may need to add webkit prefixes for it to work in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in `.gif Images` and `Animated .gif's`.

There is no javascript control over an animated gif. Your alternative is to use javascript to switch separate gif images, and that you could control. You might want to take a look at this:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp